# PHP get data OpenWeatherMap

Tags: php, openweathermap, weather-api

I want to get the weather data from the [OWM API](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London), in this case I would like to get the [temerature](http://openweathermap.org/city/2643743) and the [discription](http://openweathermap.org/city/2643743) info. How could I "pull" this from their API via PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really simple, check this code.

```
<?php

 //get JSON
 $json = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Calabar,NG&type=accurate&mode=jso‌​n');

 //decode JSON to array
 $data = json_decode($json,true);

 //show data
 var_dump($data);

 //description
 echo $data['weather'][0]['description'];
 //temperature
 echo $data['main']['temp'];


?>
```

Fist you need to get file/string with `function file_get_contents()`, in this case it is JSON string. After you need to decode this string with function `json_decode()`. Parameter **true** means that we want to parse this string to **array** instead of **object**. After this actions you can work with this dataset as it is simple variable type of array. That's all.

**EDIT:**

Edited URL based on *Prodigy* comment below

Comment: Awsome! Only have one question left ;p. What does the "[0]" mean in "echo $data['weather'][0]['description'];"?

Comment: It is index in array. They have probably multiple sensors in some towns, so there can be different temperatures (imho)

Comment: I see, so when you place "[1]" you "might" get an error?

Comment: If index 1 is not exist, you'll receive error, yes.

Comment: I think things have changed a little bit wit OWM `URL`
Change `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London` to  something like this `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Calabar,NG&type=accurate&mode=json`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Curl or file_get_contents, then save the response of either.  Then parse the response for the values you're looking for.